# How to stop events bubbling in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-bubbling

How do I stop custom event bubbling in jQuery?

For example I have this code:

```js
$('.myclass').bind('amodaldestroy', function(){
    ....does something.....
})
```

How do I only allow this to be triggered once on the first element it finds when bubbling? Can I just add return `false`?

```js
$('.myclass').bind('amodaldestroy', function(){
     ....does something.....
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$('myclass').bind('amodaldestroy'), function(event) {
    ....does something....
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [`event.stopPropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('.myclass').bind('amodaldestroy', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can also use `return false` but there is a subtle difference between the two in that returning false also calls [`event.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 8):

For support in IE < 9:

```
$(".element").click(function(e)
{
    var event = e || window.event;
    event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This might not be that great but

```
return false;
```

`return false` will do both `stopPropagation` and `event.preventDefault...`

if you want only one you can choose based on  your choice

please read this , this is from SO only

`return false` is effectively both preventDefault and stopPropogation.

`preventDefault` will prevent the default event from occuring, `stopPropogatio`n will prevent the event from bubbling up and return false will do both.

Comment: this is great, stopPropagation was failing in my case, Iguess because of many events on same element (3rd party)

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/