# JQuery - Stopping Event Bubbling in all Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, event-bubbling

I have some massively nested GUI controls - when they're clicked or changed or whatever I need to stop the event from going further up the DOM tree. It needs to work across all browsers.

At this point I've got some rather clunky JS code:

```
//Do something in response to the original user action
//Leave it at that.
try {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    catch (ex) {

    }
    try {
        event.cancelBubble();
    }
    catch (ex) {

    }

    try {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    catch (ex) { }
...
```

This does work, but it smells and feels wrong (personally I loathe empty catch blocks). Is there a neater x-browser trick I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use jQuery then just [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) will work fine. jQuery unifies the event handling.

In general if, you want to test for special browser methods, you can do like so:

```
if(event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
else if...
```

This is what jQuery is doing. It creates a wrapper for the event and provides a unified interface.

The name of the event object is defined by *you*. The event object is passed as first argument to your event handler. You have to setup the event handler to accept a parameter, e.g.:

```
$('selector').click(function(foo) { // could be event, e, bar, whatever you want
    foo.stopPropagation();
});
```

*Typically* `e` or `event` are used.

Comment: Ahhh - I was trying to call e.stopPropagation()


Thanks v. much that works perfectly.

Comment: @5arx: That depends on the parameter name. If you have `$(....).click(function(e){})`, then you have to call `e.stop...`.

Comment: Ok thanks that's good to know.

I'm calling the function from a radio button so using $(...).change(function(){...});  i.e no event parameter so I guess 'event' is a global keyword here?

Comment: @5arx: Well, it will be treated as global variable, but it will not be defined. As I said, you have to define your function to accept the parameter: `$(...).change(function(e){...});`

Comment: @FelixKing and @TimDown  Re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522257/how-do-stop-events-bubbling-in-jquery  Is @gov's answer correct? Will a simple, old skool 'return false;' cover all bases here ...?

Comment: @5arx: @gov's answer there is correct for jQuery, where `return false` calls both `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`. However, in a DOM event handler, `return false` will do nothing if the event handler was added using `addEventListener()` and is equivalent to calling `e.preventDefault()` only otherwise.

Comment: @5arx: It does, but calling the functions is more explicit and easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

`cancelBubble` is a Boolean property rather than a method of `Event` objects. There's no need for try/catch because you can test for the property or method you need before using it. So, without jQuery, the following will do what you want for an event object `e`:

```
if (typeof e.stopPropagation != "undefined") {
    e.stopPropagation();
} else if (typeof e.cancelBubble != "undefined") {
    e.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

Comment: I am using JQuery (does anyone do JavaScript dev without it these days? I think not [http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png]) but thanks for the info. One day I'll look at the JS event model properly.

One day ...

Comment: @5arx: Actually it is the DOM event model. And understanding it *now* will help you a lot for understanding how events work in general. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html. And yes JS development is still done without jQuery. It is not the solution for everything.

Comment: @5arx: I don't use jQuery: the JavaScript projects I'm working on are somewhat specialized and aren't a good fit for jQuery, plus I've been doing this stuff a long time and know the browser issues. Besides, I like to try and illustrate that life without jQuery isn't that scary.

Comment: @FelixKing & @TimDown  Cheers thanks much. I have resolved to look into DOM events on  my next '20% Day'. These days I mostly do serverside coding - my pre-Jquery forays into JS development were all about 'document.getElementById(...) and scary enough!

Thanks for the link too, looks good.