# How to handle click event on Submit Button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my script for handling submit button click event

```
$('#subbtn').on("click",function(){
    var stcode = $('.stcode11').val();
    var sem = $('.sem11').val();
    var doa = $('.doa11').val();
    $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url: 'includes/atneditprocess.php',     
         data: 'stcode='+stocde+'&sem='+sem+'&doa='+doa,
         success: function(msg)
         {
             $('.atnresult').html(msg);
         }
     });
});
```

And here is the button code

```
<button id='subbtn' type='submit' class='button'> Change </button>
```

But it not working properly. Please help me to handle click event of submit button.

Comment: `.on("click",function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Or change type to `button` instead of `submit`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do stop events bubbling in Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522257/how-do-stop-events-bubbling-in-jquery)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522257/how-do-stop-events-bubbling-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(document).on("click","#subbtn",function(e)
       {
        e.preventDefault();
         var formData = new FormData(); 
         formData.append( 'stcode', $('.stcode11').val());
         formData.append( 'sem', $('.sem11').val());
         formData.append( 'doa', $('.doa11').val());
         $.ajax({
           type:'post',
           url: 'includes/atneditprocess.php',     
           data: formData,
           success: function(msg)
           {
             $('.atnresult').html(msg);
           }
         });
   });
```

Comment: This will refresh the page as you don't prevent the default event from triggering

Comment: @DarkBee I forgot it. And it was added.

Comment: it's still wrong, you also forgot `function(e)`

Answer (score 3):

You should handle the `submit` event of `form` Then you can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to cancel the default action.

```
$('YourFormSelector').on("submit",function(event){
    //Cancel default event
    event.preventDefault();

    //Rest of your code 
});
```

Comment: here is my form code
<form class='sky-form' id='sky-form' name='liststd'>

Comment: Not working. It is not transferring to ----- url: 'includes/atneditprocess.php',
And on submission the address bar shows  :  
http://localhost/studentAttendanceEdit.php?atn=P&stcode11=1501001&doa11=2015-04-14&sem11=1

Comment: @Prasanth, You are using `$.ajax()` to submit data, What exactly you want? I think you don't need event handler at all. Create form corrretly then you won't need anything.

Comment: My processing code the for the form is "includes/atneditprocess.php".  So I use this script to handle the event without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

First, the way you are doing the submit requires you using `e.preventDefault();` to prevent your form from being submited via html.

Second, the way you pass the `data` is wrong/the way you would do for a `GET` operation. As you are trying to submit via `POST`, you need to create `data` like this:

```
data: {
    stcode : stocde
    sem : sem
    doa : doa
      }
```

Full code:

```
$('#subbtn').on("click",function(e)
                 {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     var stcode = $('.stcode11').val();
                     var sem = $('.sem11').val();
                     var doa = $('.doa11').val();
                     $.ajax({
                         type:'post',
                         url: 'includes/atneditprocess.php',     
                         data: {
                                stcode : stocde
                                sem : sem
                                doa : doa
                               }
                         success: function(msg)
                         {
                             $('.atnresult').html(msg);
                         }
                     });
                 });
```

Answer (score -1):

replace this line

```
data: 'stcode='+stcde+'&sem='+sem+'&doa='+doa,
```

with

```
data: 'stcode='+stcode+'&sem='+sem+'&doa='+doa,
```

full code with preventdefault

```
$('#subbtn').on("click",function(e) {
    var stcode = $('.stcode11').val();
    var sem = $('.sem11').val();
    var doa = $('.doa11').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'includes/atneditprocess.php',     
        data: 'stcode='+stcode+'&sem='+sem+'&doa='+doa,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $('.atnresult').html(msg);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```