# How to prevent jQuery event from bubbling when removing element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to jQuery documentation, the `event.stopPropagation();` should stop the event bubbling. In the following script, when I remove `event.stopPropagation();` the function removes the `ul` element code block including it's all children. I added `event.stopPropagation();` to stop bubbling but It returns following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'event.stopPropagation')

**The following is the HTML and jQuery code:**

```js
$('span.remove').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide(500, function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.todo-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
.todo-item {

  border: 2px solid #444;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;

}
.remove {
  float: right;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #dd0000;
}
.remove:before {
  content: 'X';
}
.remove:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.todo-item::after:hover {
  background-color: #dd0000;
  color: white;
}
.todo-item:hover {
  background-color: #0EB0FF;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='todo-list'>
  <li class='todo-item'>4L 2% Milk
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Butter, Unsalted
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Dozen Eggs
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Walk the dog
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Cut the lawn
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Laundry
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

1. [How to delete parent element using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647736/how-to-delete-parent-element-using-jquery)
2. [How to stop events bubbling in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522257/how-to-stop-events-bubbling-in-jquery)

Comment: you can access the original DOM event in `event.originalEvent`, like `event.originalEvent.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: There is no event that is being passed to your `hide` function  because it isn't an event. Put `event` in the `click, function(event)`

Comment: The `hide()` function doesn't have an event, the `.on('click', function(event) {...` does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get your `event` object from the `click()` callback. If you look at the [jquery `hide()` api docs](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), the complete callback doesn't get passed anything so your event is undefined, but [the `click()` handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/) on the other hand gets passed the event object. So you just need to change your javascript to:

```
$('span.remove').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().hide(500, function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

The reason however that the whole list gets removed is another issue. You reference `parent()` twice targeting the ul to be removed, so just get rid of one of the parents (the scope of `$(this)` changes to the parent in the hide callback). With this edit the code is:

```
$('span.remove').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().hide(500, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

It's true however that the propagation of the event, doesn't really have anything to do with the `ul` being hidden as a whole so you can just remove the `event.stopPropagation()` line. Final code being:

```
$('span.remove').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide(500, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: It removes `ul` element completely. I need to remove only the parent element of `span.remove' class.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't run it. I edited my answer to account for that. I hope that clarifies

Answer (score 2):

Move event obj to the delegated click event.

Instead of `this` use `event.target`.

```js
$('span.remove').on('click', function(event) {
  var tgt = event.target;
  $(tgt).parent().hide(500, function() {
    $(tgt).parent().remove();
     
  });
 
});
```

```css
.todo-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
.todo-item {

  border: 2px solid #444;
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;

}
.remove {
  float: right;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #dd0000;
}
.remove:before {
  content: 'X';
}
.remove:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.todo-item::after:hover {
  background-color: #dd0000;
  color: white;
}
.todo-item:hover {
  background-color: #0EB0FF;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='todo-list'>
  <li class='todo-item'>4L 2% Milk
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Butter, Unsalted
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Dozen Eggs
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Walk the dog
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Cut the lawn
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
  <li class='todo-item'>Laundry
    <span class='remove'></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm glad it did, sir. @KevinB done, I didn't have time test it thoroughly just enough to get a result, thanks.

Comment: @MaihanNijat this solution removes the li of the `event.target`, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you. I voted up your answer as it achieve what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems:

1. **The `event` variable is not being passed**. Don't include the `event` parameter in the `hide()` function, but rather in the `on()` event handler. This should stop the error.
2. **You are removing the parent of the parent.** Replace the following line: `$(this).parent().remove();` with `$(this).remove();`
3. **You actually don't need the `stopPropagation()`**. After fixing the above two problems, you don't need it. The `click` event is not propagating.

Comment: @KevinB Oops. Edited.