# Nested collapses calling parent collapse every time

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've searched and found a few similar answers - but those were surrounding accordions which I am not using.

I have nested collapse items [as seen in this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djLjPe)

```js
$('#collapseOutter').on('show.bs.collapse', function(event) {
  $('#collapseBtn').html("Show Less");
  console.log('Only happen when outter div is opened');
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('even with stopping propagation it fires');
})
$('#collapseOutter').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('#collapseBtn').html("Show More");
  console.log('Only happen when outter div is collapsed');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ml-4">
    <div class="row header-div">
      <a id="collapseBtn" class="btn-info btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOutter" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOutter">
    Show More
  </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ml-4">
    <div id="collapseOutter" class="collapse">
      <p>Here is a paragraph about the data you're about to see.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="item-a">
          <a id="item-a" class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseInnerA">
      Item One of a list
     </a>
          <br />
          <div id="collapseInnerA" class="collapse">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="ml-4">Item One Related Information</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="item-b">
          <a id="item-b" class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseInnerB">
      Item Two of a list
     </a>
          <br />
          <div id="collapseInnerB" class="collapse">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="ml-4">Item Two Related Information</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the items in the list (which is inside the 1st collapse) it causes the parent methods to fire.

How do I prevent the parent methods from firing when I click on the list items to collapse/show their information?

I'm looking to see how I can do this relating to bootstrap specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop events bubbling in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522257/how-to-stop-events-bubbling-in-jquery)

Comment: Again - I've searched. I see it's called 'event bubbling', but that doesn't help me with how to resolve my issue related to Bootstrap and collapsing. That link you gave is for custom functions - how would I do that with default Bootstrap functions?

Comment: Can you not use `event.stopPropagation()` in your event functions?

Comment: I've included that in the `.on('show.bs.collapse')` function and it doesn't do anything. I will edit to show - I have included that in the show function and it still fires off.

Comment: I see I can add a class to the inner elements now - and use that `stopPropagation` when I call `show` and `hide` on the class applied to the inner elements. It seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are stopping the event propagation when it reaches the outer collapse. You should stop it on the inner collapses. In [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBQPeO), the first inner collapse's collapse event will bubble while the second is stopped.

```
$('#collapseInnerB').on('show.bs.collapse', function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
})
$('#collapseInnerB').on('hide.bs.collapse', function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```